# Taylor's Theorem Proof: Confused About the Validity of Two Inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

My textbook gives the following proof of the single-variable version of Taylor's theorem:

> As promised, we begin with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, written in the form
>
> $$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f'(\tau) \ d \tau$$
>
> Next, we write $d \tau = - d(x_0 + h - \tau)$ and integrate parts to give
>
> $$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) = f'(x_0) h + \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f''(\tau)(x_0 + h - \tau) \ d \tau,$$
>
> which is the first-order Taylor formula. Integrating by parts again, we get
>
> $$\int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f''(\tau)(x_0 + h - \tau) \ d\tau = - \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f''(\tau) d(x_0 + h - \tau)^2$$
>
> $$= \dfrac{1}{2} f''(x_0) h^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f'''(\tau)(x_0 + h - \tau)^2 \ d \tau,$$
>
> which, when substituted into the preceding formula, gives the **second-order Taylor formula**:
>
> $$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0) h + \dfrac{1}{2}f''(x_0) h^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f'''(\tau)(x_0 + h - \tau)^2 \ \ d\tau$$
>
> Taylor's theorem for general $k$ proceeds by repeated integration by parts. The statement (2) that $\dfrac{R_k(x_0, h)}{h^k} \to 0$ as $h \to 0$, is seen as follows. For $\tau$ in the interval $[x_0, x_0 + h]$, we have $[x_0 + h - \tau] \le |h|$, and $f^{k + 1} (\tau)$, being continuous, is bounded; say, $\left| f^{k + 1}(\tau) \right| \le M$. Then
>
> $$| R_k(x_0, h) | = \left| \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} \dfrac{(x_0 + h - \tau)^k}{k!} f^{k + 1}(\tau) \ d \tau \right| \le \dfrac{|h|^{k + 1}}{k!} M$$
>
> and, in particular, $\left| \dfrac{R_k(x_0, h)}{h^k} \right| \le \dfrac{|h| M}{k!} \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

I have two points of confusion:

1. How is $| R_k(x_0, h) | = \left| \displaystyle\int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} \dfrac{(x_0 + h - \tau)^k}{k!} f^{k + 1}(\tau) \ d \tau \right| \le \dfrac{|h|^{k + 1}}{k!} M$ true? This is not clear to me. For instance, it is stated that $[x_0 + h - \tau] \le |h|$ and $\left| f^{k + 1}(\tau) \right| \le M$; fine. But I still don't see how this makes the above inequality true.
2. By extension, how is $\left| \dfrac{R_k(x_0, h)}{h^k} \right| \le \dfrac{|h| M}{k!} \to 0$ as $h \to 0$ true? This is also not clear to me.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $a \lt b$ and we know that for a measurable function $g$ defined on $(a,b)$ we have $x \in (a,b) \to |g(x)| \le M$, then it follows that
$$
\bigg|\int_a^b g(x) dx \bigg| \le (b - a)M
$$

in your example $b - a = h$ and $|x_0 + h - \tau|^k \le |h|^k$. Together with $\left| f^{k + 1}(\tau) \right| \le M$ these values give the required bound on the integral

Comment: sorry there is a typo. my text should have read $b-a = h$. i have corrected this in the answer

Comment: sorry i could not be of more assistance

Comment: Ok, I think I understand this now. This follows the principle of Riemann sums -- the same principle used in the proof of the Riemann integral.